# Increment a counter in database

Tags: php, sql

I need to set a counter for the visitor of each page.
the script for protect link
this is example for link
http://www.science-union.com/upload/m1.php?id=356

The database contains a table `data`.

The table contains 5 fields for all links:

- id
- title
- url
- size
- email

I added a new field and renamed it to `download` and fetched it in PHP file but it still shows `0`.
look in example
before Download button
I need to php code  increase the download number for every visitor of the page.

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: Yeah, rewrite your question please

Comment: I tried to edit it, but we still need more information.

Comment: Show us some code please. How do you guess we should be able to help you if we can't magically guess what code you already have?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html

Comment: adding some information and example , I'm sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE data SET downloaded = downloaded + 1
```

Is that what you're looking for?